# NSEvent doesn't work

Tags: post, keyboard, keystroke, simulate, nsevent

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the following code. I want to simulate an "a".

```
NSEvent* keyEvent = [NSEvent keyEventWithType:NSKeyDown location:NSZeroPoint modifierFlags:NSCommandKeyMask timestamp:0 windowNumber:[windowNumber intValue] context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] characters:@"A" charactersIgnoringModifiers:nil isARepeat:NO keyCode:0];
[NSApp postEvent:keyEvent atStart:NO];
```